# How to change the new font in Visual studio 2013 back to 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I don't like the new font in Visual studio 2013.
I liked the font in Visual studio 2012.

In Visual studio 2013 :
Environment, Fonts, .. Text Editor :  Consolas, 10

But in Visual studio 2012, it shows the exact same values and screen.
Is there something else I can change to make it like  2012?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the text editor and seeing the difference?

Comment: On a Windows machine, the font you get when you type an SO question is, drumroll, Consolas.

Comment: I mean OP is not looking at the output window and expecting that font to change.

Comment: The window in Visual Studio I'm talking about is the one used for the C# and html code. Maybe there is another option in VS that control that "Environment, Fonts, .. Text Editor" isn't the one I want.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the editor font problem described [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800283/change-of-consolas-font-rendering-in-vs2013), then the only workaround is to use Consolas 11 and 91% editor zoom. It's a rather annoying workaround because you have to set 91% for every newly open document.

You should also upvote the bug on that Connect page, maybe they will fix it eventually. (They don't seem to pay attention to it right now.)